# locationForGlyphAtIndex returning wrong value

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-text, textkit

I'm trying to get the location of glyphs in an `NSLayoutManager`, but on a few isolated occasions I'm getting what appears to be incorrect values.

For example: two `f`'s together in Helvetica Neue size 16. The x value of the 2nd `f` should be around 4, but I'm getting 9.232000..? Anyone know why this is?

```
NSString *lettersString = @"ff";
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16]
};

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lettersString attributes:attrsDictionary];
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];

NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;

[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

CGPoint location = [layoutManager locationForGlyphAtIndex:1];

// location.x == 9.232000
```

Comment: I think 9.232000 is a proper value for 16th HelveticaNeue. I've created a label with those parameters and its intrinsic size is 14x23.

Comment: @Astoria if I have 'fff', then the position of the 3rd letter also comes back as 9.232000...? How can the 2nd and 3rd letter both have the same x position in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! iOS automatically resolves ligatures (one or more letters joined as a single glyph) unless explicitly disabled in the string attributes.

So the `ff` characters in this example are converted into a single character at `\uniFB00` - which is of course wider.

Comment: OMG thanks. I was beating my head against a wall for a good 30 minutes about why "fi" was giving weird values for locationForGlyphAtIndex.